# Initializing EJB Security Context from credentials provided via SAML in WS-Security Header in JBoss EAP 7.1 / Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, cxf, ws-security

I intend to secure provided SOAP web services by means of applying particular WS-Security policies, in particular "SAML 2.0 Bearer" and "SAML 2.0 Sender Vouches". The credentials provided in the SAML tokens should be used to initialize an EJB Security Context to apply proper user authorization in the EJB part of the application.

I've been successful in leveraging the embedded Apache CXF to secure the web services as such and also to initialize the web service security context (`WebServiceContext.getUserPrincipal()`). However, I fail to propagate the user context from the web service context to the EJB session context (`SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()`). 
Any advice on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

So far, I'd expect to need to realize functionality similar to the documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/WS-Security#WS-Security-Authenticationandauthorization, that is, create a CXF interceptor similar to https://github.com/jbossws/jbossws-cxf/blob/master/modules/server/src/main/java/org/jboss/wsf/stack/cxf/security/authentication/SubjectCreatingPolicyInterceptor.java that uses the credentials provided in the SAML tokens to create an EJB security context.

Comment: Some documentation on an apparently very similar issue here: https://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/158-Certificates-and-WS-Security-with-JavaEE-integration-in-Wildfly.html

Comment: Raising the issue with Red Hat resulted in this feature request: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-4123